# SVN Gnome Keyring - RHEL 6 - Keyring takes any password

Tags: svn, redhat, gnome-keyring-daemon

After following a various assortment of steps from different guides that I found - I think I have Subversion with Gnome Keyring set up.

Part of the setup process was making a keyring for SVN, and then setting it as default. I created it and made a password for that keyring. I then set it as default. I made the necessary changes to servers and config (such as password-stores gnome keyring, etc)

When I create a new test directory (i.e testsvn) and cd to it, I can run

```
'svn checkout <url>'
```

It will prompt me for my password, which I'll type in - then it says password for 'svn' keyring - which seemed like it would be all set up - butt I can type in anything. I can type in the right  I can type in anything, including nothing, and hitting enter, and then it will say ' "Checked out at revision ____" ' which I feel like is wrong?

At that point shouldn't the password I type in have to match the one I set for when I created the SVN keyring password? Has anyone had any experience with this?

*I am using RHEl 6.7, and Subversion 1.9.4 from CollabNet which already came with the keyring tool. (just for reference of the version I am using in case that helps)*

Thanks!